# mongodb shell query with java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java, nosql

How to write this **mongodb** shell query with using java?

**query :**  `db.building_feature.find({geometry : {$geoIntersects :{$geometry :{type : "Polygon", coordinates :[[[37.59777,55.73216],[37.59805,55.77615],[37.68710,55.77643],[37.68517,55.73290],[37.59777,55.73216]]]}}}})`

My collection GeoSpatialIndex is "**2dsphere**".

My version  which is not working :

```
DBCollection testCollection = db.getCollection("building_feature");  
final LinkedList<double[]> geo = new LinkedList<>();
geo.addLast(new double[]{37.59777, 55.73216});
geo.addLast(new double[]{37.59805, 55.77615});
geo.addLast(new double[]{37.68710, 55.77643});
geo.addLast(new double[]{37.68517, 55.73290});

final BasicDBObject query
    = new BasicDBObject("geometry", new BasicDBObject("$within", new BasicDBObject("$geometry", geo)));
System.out.println("Result Count : " + testCollection.find(query).count());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write exactly the same query in Java:

```
BasicDBObject polygon = new BasicDBObject("type", "Polygon");
polygon.put("coordinates", <myArray>);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(
    "geometry", new BasicDBObject(
        "$geoIntersects", new BasicDBObject(
            "$geometry", polygon
        )
    )
);
```

`<myArray>` being your triple-nested `double[][][]` geoJSON polygon coordinates array.

Btw, it could be more clear to read with a JSON string and then `JSON.parse`.

And I think `$whithin` operator does not exist in MongoDB...

Comment: Thanks, can you give example "GeoJSONPolygonBasicDBObject" ?

Comment: Well, this is basic Java, and I think it is out of the purpose of the question, which concerns MongoDB API for Java. You don't want me to write all your code, I'm sure that Google will tell you how to create arrays in Java ;)